# What does it mean to "not awaken love until it pleases"?

Tags: song-of-songs, sexuality

It says 3 times in Song of Solomon, "don't awaken love until it pleases". What does awakening love until it pleases exactly mean?

> - **SOS 2:7 ESV** I adjure you, O daughters of Jerusalem, by the gazelles or the does of the field, that you not stir up or **awaken love until it pleases**.
> - **SOS 3:5 ESV** I adjure you, O daughters of Jerusalem, by the gazelles or the does of the field, that you not stir up or **awaken love until it pleases**.
> - **SOS 8:4 ESV** I adjure you, O daughters of Jerusalem, that you not stir up or **awaken love until it pleases**.

There's two parts to the question: awakening love, and pleasing it.

The obvious explanation is sex and marriage: don't have sex (awaken love) until you're married (pleasing it). But I feel like it goes much deeper than that, particularly the part about awakening love. Pleasing love seems to clearly talk about marriage within the context of SOS because the culmination of the book is about a marriage, but the part about awakening love is more abstract to me. Beyond just sex or lust, what else could it be talking about?

Comment: Ok, after some searching I found a duplicate topic, it appears @Caleb means this link.  http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8375/what-does-do-not-arouse-or-awaken-love-until-it-so-desires-mean?rq=1